# Is there any other function except upper which can help to make all character of a string in uppercase?

Tags: python, string, uppercase

I was trying to make string's all character in uppercase but as string is immutable in python i am not getting this permanently in string. is there any function or alternative to get that?

```
message = "Have a great day"    
print(message.upper())    
message.upper()    
print(message)
```

first print is giving all in caps but second is returning same string with no changes...

Comment: If a string is immutable, *no* function is going to be able to change it.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. You _have_ the right method; the question is how to keep the result it gives. Assign it to a new variable (or back to `message` if you want to overwrite it).

Comment: In first case you print the new string.  In the second you are throwing it away.

Answer (score 1):

You could store it as a variable so:

```
message = "Have a great day"    
print(message.upper())    
message = message.upper() # Could store it as a different variable, 
                          # if you don't want it to overwrite 
print(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Sting: Thank you for asking in Stackoverflow. I see this is your first time.
what happens is that upper is a method and returns a value.

In the case of print(message.upper()) you are passing the returned value of the method to print and print take it and print it to the standard output

That is not happening on message.upper(), you are not capturing the returned value
Below code fix that.

Hope it helps.!!

```
message = "Have a great day"
print(message.upper())
l= message.upper()
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign your message to a variable

```
message = "Have a great day"
print(message.upper())
uppercase_message = message.upper()
print(uppercase_message)
```

Comment: I was too slow. Should I delete redundant answers?

Comment: No, you can keep your answer. You can even edit it to make it better than existing answers by adding links to documentation, explanation, comments, etc. :)

Comment: Thanks @iz_ ! You're nice and helpful.